# implement atoi() of C in PHP

Tags: php, c, algorithm, atoi

There's a function in C, atoi(), implement this in PHP;

- $string = '5467'; //function should return 5467 as integer

So this is what I found (`its implementation in C`)

```
int myatoi(const char *string) {
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(*string) {
        i = (i<<3) + (i<<1) + (*string - '0');
        string++;
    }
```

Comment: Programming *is* problem solving. It's easy enough to learn a new programming language. A lot harder to teach/learn how to problem solve.

Comment: I would not implement *= 10 by `<<3 plus <<1`, but leave that to the compiler. Even in PHP. Also a for loop would save you two lines. Does PHP have for() loops?

Comment: @LeeTaylor 100% Right, as we learn thing from StackOverFlow.com by problem solving.

Comment: When I'm in an interview like this, the only problem for me to solve is finding the door. It sounds like a stupid question to me.

Comment: `"567" -> ((5 * 10 + 6) * 10) + 7` here the clever bit is that `*10` is implemented with a bit-shift for performance reasons... but I don't think that bit was expected from you, may be just the parsing / conversion part. I think it's a pretty fair question.

Comment: @Asiri Rathnayake: using shift for multiplication is *not* clever. it's a dump assumption. trust your compiler, it can do a better job in optimisation than you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: As far as I know ALUs are much efficient at shifting bits rather than adding / multiplying / dividing two numbers. But may be this difference is only important if you are really really really concerned about performance, and it could also be that modern compilers can do this automatically (convert to shifts) for you...

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake: that was true in 1980. Nowadays processors are faster than the memory bus, even for multiplication. BTW: I believe PHP is based on a P-code interpreter. Fetching and processing the three opcodes (for 2* shift + 1*add) will probably cost more than the multiplication itself.

Comment: @wildplasser: Do you have a reference to some resource that compares the performance of the two approaches? A multiplication would require two arguments to be fetched over the memory bus, but a shift can be packed into a single instruction AFAIK. Anyway, don't want to steal the discussion, will do some testing on my own, thanks for bringing this up. Cheers! (PS: I was talking about shifting in the above program, not in PHP)

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake: I just did the experiment (create two functions one using multiply, one with shift; added the return, BTW) And: compiled with `gcc -O1 -S multshift.c`. The resulting multshift.s shows *almost* the same assembly for the two functions (at least the *number* of instructions in the loop body is the same) Performance-wise, the loop *itself* is the most costly part (because of the pipeline drain), but maybe the repz prefix has been resurrected after the 386.

Comment: @wildplasser: Great! I've also started doing some performance tests and also couldn't note much of a difference (Yet). But lot more to go and it'll definitely take a long time for me to complete. Will probably raise a question on StackOverflow once I have a done a good survey. Thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake: please don't micro-optimise. (though you can *learn* from it: that is: you learn: don't micro-optimise ...) A multi-boxed pipelined processor will execute an instruction in zero or one tick, and will spend the rest of the time waiting for the memory bus. Having four cores on the same bus does not help much either. It is all about caching and branch prediction, nowadays. The biggest win is to keep memory acces *local*, avoiding all the cache stalls. And: *speed kills* (hint: in most cases a linear search is better if the number of entries is smaller than, say, 100 ints)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19605/discussion-between-asiri-rathnayake-and-wildplasser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know PHP but if the point was to see if you could write the algorithm, I can show how I'd approach this in C. (Untested code here.)

```
int atoi(char *s)
{
    int val = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        val *= 10;
        val += (*s) - '0';
        s++;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what you mean with (*s) -'0';

Comment: This converts the current character to the equivalent value: '0' is a character, which C can treat like numbers. So '0' - '0' = 0, '1' - '0' = 1, '2' - '0' = 2, '3' - '0' = 3, etc.

Comment: @vknyvz because '0' isn't really 0 it's ascii for some number (don't really remember which) and you need to delete that offset from it

Comment: @qwertymk: It's easy to remember. '0' is equal to the ASCII value of the character '0', which is 48. :) Since I don't care about 48 here, I just use the character.

Comment: yea i know in PHP though '0' isn't really 0 if you do === but in theory you can get away by saying '0' is 0 coz the language is loosely typed so you wouldn't care, i know C++ and C especially not forgiven

Comment: @JonathanWood exactly, I do remember that the difference between `'A'` and `'a'` is `' '` or 32(`x20`)

Comment: C is closer to the hardware. In a text file that contains the character '0', the raw value stored is actually 48. Yes, PHP is doing a conversion for you to treat numeric characters as the values they represent.

Comment: what about "-42" ?

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question:

```
function atoi($string)
{
  return (int) $string;
}
```

It sounds like a trick question to see if you understand the concept of php as a loosely typed language. So yes, it's fair to ask.

Comment: I know guys you Programming is definitely problem solving, and I am looking into ways to improve this but can you guys answer any of my questions, is this really fair? how would you implement this in php and any way of improving this `problem solving` skill?

Comment: simple but nobody seem to be able to answer in PHP. this casting thing you did was my first response (int) nope he didn't like that at all

Comment: @vknyvz That is solving the problem based on the criteria you have (input and output). I would say that that is exactly what problem solving is about; it is not about translating a function simply line by line to another language.

Comment: @vknyvz: did you ask *why* he didn't like it?

Answer (score 2):

It's really just:

```
function myatoi($s) {
    return (int) $s;
}
```

I think it's a good think that they are looking for your problem solving skills. A good senior developer would probably come up with the following interesting observations:

- What should my function return if the data is not valid (eg: "a"). 0? Throw an exception? Your C example will return some garbage (even for "15a", for which the standard says you should return 15).
- Your C example cannot handle negative numbers.
- What should be the result if the number doesn't fit into an integer? Your C example will simply overflow (which is BTW completely valid in C).

Comment: How does this demonstrate problem solving skills? It simply shows you know the difference between the languages.

Comment: Part of the problem solving is understanding the requirements / API, and, if needed, ask questions...

Comment: true, but wouldn't simply asking why the solution was needed in the first place demonstrate better problem solving? Sometimes getting to the root of the problem is the best approach.

Comment: you see, another question :) it's not needed in arithmetic context, but if you use a lot of numbers, you might do the conversion to lower the memory footprint, so there are valid scenarios... and then you could have another conversation about this subject. I think a good programmer can show his skills even when faced with the simplest tasks.

Comment: This is why these questions (in interviews) are so asinine. They are so subjective. Look at all the opinions in the thread.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath any suggestion on a real implementation in PHP at least pseudo, jobs already gone, i just want to know this

Comment: @relentless: asinine? only with a stupid interviewer...

Comment: I guess that's just been my experience ;)

Comment: @vknyvz: same as C. but since it's PHP, it's not a null terminated string (well, internally it probably is, but not exposed to you..). just process each character... can you write a loop to process a string char-by-char?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath oh most definitely you can use `str_split` built-in function, but from my experiences during interviews, interviewers never let you use built-in functions.
you can also do it with regex `'/(?<!^)(?!$)/u'` but this would still return chars as string

Comment: jesus... it's a simple `for` loop and array indexing. if you overcomplicate such a simple task, no wonder the interviewer is not impressed.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath this was exactly my answer which was unacceptable.